# Default font and font size in LibreOffice Calc 4.2.3.3

Tags: libreoffice

I have LibreOffice Version: 4.2.3.3, Build ID: 420m0(Build:3) installed from the Software Center. My OS is Lubuntu 14.04.

I want to have `Liberation Sans 11` as my default font. How do I do that?

If I open a new spreadsheet the font is `Liberation Sans 10`.

If I select the whole spreadsheet and specify `Liberation Sans 11`, whatever I type is in `Liberation Sans 11` but if I use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>X</kbd> to cut the contents of a cell, and come back later to that same cell and enter text there, the font size is back to **10** in *that* cell.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Start by clicking on the `Format` menu. and then select `Styles and Formatting`.  You should then see the Styles and Formatting window.  Right-click on `Default` and select `Modify` (as shown below):

[image: the Styles and Formatting window]

On the next window, click on the `Font` tab at the top:

[image]

From here, you should be able to modify the default font.

Answer (score 0):

This approach maybe changes the font only once, it will get back to previous settings when you open a new calc. 
The optimal way is as follows:

1. open a new calc file, change the font as upper way.
2. save this file as a template: File->template->manage
3. set your template as default

Then, your calc font will change to what you want every time when you create a new calc file